# Why does "in the theatre" have a definite article?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

This is a definition from Cambridge Dictionary for the word "stooge":

> an actor in a funny show in **the** theatre or on television whose job is to allow the main actor to make him or her look silly

Why is the article "the" used here? The stooge is called the same in any theatre, not just a particular one.

Answer (score 4):

"The" can refer to particular instances of things, such as a particular theater, as in "*the theater* at the corner of 43rd Ave and Main Street".  But it can also be used to refer to activities, places, professions, etcetera in a generic, abstract, collective or representative manner:

- He is in the army.
- He is in the hospital. (American English)
- He is active in the theater.
- He lost a lot of money betting on the horses.
- The bottle has always been a problem for him.
- He always had a love of the mountains.
- He was pugnacious and destined for the ring.

Comment: Good answer, +1. I'm not completely sure about "in the hospital" though - I'm looking into the American use, but certainly, in British English we say "in hospital" to mean that someone has been hospitalised, "in *the* hospital" would mean a specific hospital, likely the local, or the most obvious one that a person would be in, and that's the very opposite of all your other examples.

Comment: @Astralbee: In American English "He is in *the hospital*" means "He is hospitalized" unless circumstances would license the more specific meaning. If the police were pursuing a person who just robbed a person,  people on the street who had seen the robber fleeing might say to the officers "He's in the hospital, not in the Burger King. We saw him go in."  In that case it refers to the building itself.  P.S. I'm a native speaker of American English, BTW.

Comment: I've learned something I did not know about US English. https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/in-hospital-or-in-the-hospital

Comment: From the article: *There doesn’t seem to be any logical reason why we use the word **the** here. It’s rarely added for similar terms.*   It's used more often than the author realizes.