# Why is the article ommited in this context?

Tags: grammar, articles

This is an extract from a book "Black Rednecks And White Liberals" by Thomas Sowell.

He is talking about behavioral patterns of peoples living in the south of the U.S in colonial times.

"The pattern **is one** said by Professor McWhiney to go back to descriptions of ancient Celts as “boasters and threateners, and given to bombastic self-dramatization.”

I know from a previous topic that I posted that the articles are omitted when we are speaking
about nouns in a generic, abstract, collective or representative manner[Why does "in the theatre" have a definite article?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310251/why-does-in-the-theatre-have-a-definite-article/310252#310252)
How does it apply here?

why is the article omitted before the word "one" here?

Comment: Where do you think there should be an article? What is omitted is **which is** or **that is**.  The Professor says that this pattern of behaviour is one which goes back to the ancient Celts.

Comment: Additionally, "one" stands in for "a pattern": "The pattern is a pattern that is said to go back to...", but it seldom sounds good to repeat words like that.

Comment: I think it should either be: ''The pattern is the one said..." or "The pattern is a one said" although the latter  doesn't sound right to me for some reason and I guess, what I would like to know is what reason this is.

Comment: We never use the indefinite article with _one_ (except in the colloquial expression [you are a one!](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/you-are-he-is-a-one)). "I have some pretty flowers in my garden. Here is one I have just picked." (an unidentified flower). "Here is the one I told you about." (a particular flower that has been mentioned already)

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you.